# How do I organize an array that is an html line containing variables pulled from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, sql-order-by

I am attempting to alphabetically organize an options list populated from an array; the problem is that the array array contains html tags at the front so sorting it seems imposable. I have tried 'ORDER BY' in the mysql query from which the array variables are pulled, but the command gets lost.

The whole system seems hardwired to sort the list by the key column in the mysql table, which is simply not acceptable. Is there any way around this issue? Any help would be VERY appreciated!

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$options = array();
$query1=mysql_query("Select * From table1 Where name='blah'");
while($queryvalue1=mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$array1 = $queryvalue1['Column1'];
$query2=mysql_query("Select * From table2 Where id In ($array1) Order by value DESC");
while($queryvalue2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $var1 = $queryvalue2['Column2'];
    $var2 = $queryvalue2['Column3'];
    $options[] = "<option value='$var'>$var2</option>"
  }
}
 $options = implode(PHP_EOL, $options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's certainly ways to do it, but they are all much slower than letting the database sort for you.

It might not be the simplest solution, but I'd suggest getting rid of the HTML tags and repopulating the database, even if you have to use a temporary table while you fix the rest of your code. Do it right so you don't have to continually work around a serious problem for the rest of the application lifecycle.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I am not quite understanding it. Why would I need to revise my database? To assign the column I want to organize with as the new key column? Otherwise I just don't see how I could modify my database to resolve this issue. Furthermore, if you wouldn't mind giving me an example of a way I can do what I'm trying to do sans changing my database that would be great, if for no other reason than to learn a little bit more. Thanks again!

Comment: I mean, remove the HTML from the values in the database, in this case 'Column3', and add it back on as needed in the code anytime it's used.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I explained myself well (I was afraid of that). There is no html in my database, The html is embedded in the array to format my variables from the database the way I want them. $var1 and $var2 are the values and the array is structured $array="<OPTION VALUE='$var1'>$var2". since all values in the array begin "<OPTION..." I'm having trouble getting them sorted the way I want them; alphabetically according to $var2. Hopefully that explains it, if not I guess I don't deserve to have my question answered :P ...sorry if it's a stupid question, still learning.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. In that case, change it to `$options[$val2] = ...` and then you can `ksort($options);` to sort it by the keys (in this case, the values of val2). For more complicated sorts, you need a usort(). Odd that SQL ORDER BY Column3 didn't work, that's pretty standard SQL.